# In Eclipse, how can I access a resource in another project?

Tags: java

I have two projects in Eclipse and one has the class which has the 'main' function.
Let's call this project as 'A'.
And in this 'main' function, it instantiate a class in another project. Let's call this project and and the class, 'B' and 'C' respectively. In class 'C', it tries to load a RESOURCEFILE from the project 'B' by using 'System.property("user.dir")".

When I try to run this application from the project 'A', it can't get the RESOURCEFILE opened which is in project B because the working directory is in project 'A'. But I need to put the file in project 'B'.

I don't what is the best way to get this problem solved. Do I need to pass the information of the project B when I am running this application? I am totally lost..

I will wait for someone's help!

gim

Comment: 1. Set "user.dir" property within project A to point to B's directory while C loads its resource. 2. Use "classpath:resource" or any other type of access in class C instead of using system properties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you point me to some further information about 'classpath:resource'? And if you can tell me what you mean by 'any other type of access', it will be great.

Comment: My answer is related to @Stephen C's one. In your case you can just use `YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/resource-package/resource-name.txt")`. In some other projects, that involve major Java frameworks, you may need to use other functions and specify resource as a full URI. That is, use http: //url.of.resource.com" or "file:///path/to/file" or "classpath:resource-name.txt". But in simplest case like yours `getResourceAsStream()` is enough. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java) question for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Add the second project to the build path of the first as a project dependency.

Comment: I think he have already done this, since he is able to instantiate class from project B in main function of project A.

Comment: Maybe I am not clear in explaining the problem. I have added the second project to the first project's build path. And that's how I am able to instantiate class 'C'.

Comment: woops I pressed enter key in wrong time. sorry. The thing is when I am trying to load a file from class 'C', it tries to find a file from project 'A', not in project 'C' because the working folder is the project 'A'.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you haven't thought through the problem of how these projects are going to be deployed.  Are they separate command-line applications?  Are they separate web-apps?  At they components of a larger application / web-app?

If these projects are components and the resources you are trying to access (effectively) part of your source-code base, then the best way to access them is by using `Class.getResource(...)` or `Class.getResourceAsStream(...)`.  For the deployed version, you simply need to ensure that the JAR file for `B` contains the resources, and is on the runtime classpath.

If these projects are in fact distinct, then your problem is more tricky, and the best solution depends on exactly how they are to be deployed and configured.

(The `getResource(...)` method gives you a URL.  If you actually want to read it, use `getResourceAsStream(...)`.)

---

About the argument for `getResourceAsStream`:  The argument is a path that is resolved in the namespace of the class container; e.g. your `classes` directory or (when deployed) your JAR file.  You can choose between a relative or absolute path.  An absolute path will be resolved relative to the root of the container.  A relative path will be resolved relative to the path of the parent of the class (assuming you are using `Class.getResourceAsStream`.

AFAIK, Eclipse automatically copies resources from your source tree into the project's classes directory, but you may want to check that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. They are not a separate command-line applications. One project has the 'main' function and the component in the other project is just instantiated from the 'main' function. I will look into Class.getResource and Class.getResourceAsStream and update the posting. Thank you again.

Comment: Umm.. I got some trouble already. I don't know what to put as an argument in using Class.getResource. Can you give me a hint? I don't think I should use an absolute path. I had no idea it's so hard to load a file from a different project.